# Google Map Marker Cluster error when using custom icons

Tags: android, google-maps, markerclusterer, markers

Currently developing android mobile application with 500+ markers.I'm using marker cluster function in order to give clear view of the google map.I have implemented both **ClusterItem** and **DefaultClusterRenderer** classes.

**ClusterItem** class provides marker cluster function and  **DefaultClusterRenderer** provides custom icons other than default red balloon.

Once I implemented DefaultClusterRenderer class and changed icon only it gives me the following error. It is login properly in the beginning but once I tried to zoom the map the error occurs.

Logcat points to default implematation of the classes
Logcat output as follows

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.google.maps.android.clustering.view.DefaultClusterRenderer.onClusterItemUpdated(DefaultClusterRenderer.java:789)
        at com.google.maps.android.clustering.view.DefaultClusterRenderer$CreateMarkerTask.perform(DefaultClusterRenderer.java:973)
        at com.google.maps.android.clustering.view.DefaultClusterRenderer$CreateMarkerTask.access$2000(DefaultClusterRenderer.java:934)
        at com.google.maps.android.clustering.view.DefaultClusterRenderer$MarkerModifier.performNextTask(DefaultClusterRenderer.java:650)
        at com.google.maps.android.clustering.view.DefaultClusterRenderer$MarkerModifier.handleMessage(DefaultClusterRenderer.java:621)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

it points to default implementation, any idea how to solve this matter?

Comment: It seems there is a bug. https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/673

Answer (score 4):

Apparently this is a bug at Google Maps Utils library, you can see related the thread from [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/673)

Until they release the new version i found a workaround. As you mention you implemented the DefaultClusterRenderer class. If you didn't override onClusterUpdatedItem method like me, override this method with the correct version of code from library.

If you are using java

```
protected void onClusterItemUpdated(T item, Marker marker) {
        boolean changed = false;
        // Update marker text if the item text changed - same logic as adding marker in CreateMarkerTask.perform()
        if (item.getTitle() != null && item.getSnippet() != null) {
            if (!item.getTitle().equals(marker.getTitle())) {
                marker.setTitle(item.getTitle());
                changed = true;
            }
            if (!item.getSnippet().equals(marker.getSnippet())) {
                marker.setSnippet(item.getSnippet());
                changed = true;
            }
        } else if (item.getSnippet() != null && !item.getSnippet().equals(marker.getTitle())) {
            marker.setTitle(item.getSnippet());
            changed = true;
        } else if (item.getTitle() != null && !item.getTitle().equals(marker.getTitle())) {
            marker.setTitle(item.getTitle());
            changed = true;
        }
        // Update marker position if the item changed position
        if (!marker.getPosition().equals(item.getPosition())) {
            marker.setPosition(item.getPosition());
            changed = true;
        }
        if (changed && marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
            // Force a refresh of marker info window contents
            marker.showInfoWindow();
        }
    }
```

or if you are using Kotlin

```
override fun onClusterItemUpdated(item: YOUR_MARKER_ITEM_CLASS?, marker: Marker?) {
        var changed = false
        // Update marker text if the item text changed - same logic as adding marker in CreateMarkerTask.perform()
        // Update marker text if the item text changed - same logic as adding marker in CreateMarkerTask.perform()
        if (item!!.title != null && item!!.snippet != null) {
            if (!item!!.title.equals(marker!!.title)) {
                marker!!.title = item!!.title
                changed = true
            }
            if (!item!!.snippet.equals(marker!!.snippet)) {
                marker!!.snippet = item!!.snippet
                changed = true
            }
        } else if (item!!.snippet != null && !item!!.snippet.equals(marker!!.title)) {
            marker!!.title = item!!.snippet
            changed = true
        } else if (item!!.title != null && !item!!.title.equals(marker!!.title)) {
            marker!!.title = item!!.title
            changed = true
        }
        // Update marker position if the item changed position
        // Update marker position if the item changed position
        if (!marker!!.position.equals(item!!.position)) {
            marker!!.position = item!!.position
            changed = true
        }
        if (changed && marker!!.isInfoWindowShown) {
            // Force a refresh of marker info window contents
            marker!!.showInfoWindow()
        }
    }
```

At least this little workaround solved the problem until they release next version.

**EDIT:**
I also suggest you to leave Google Maps Utils library and use [this](https://github.com/sharewire/google-maps-clustering) library for clustering. It is much more suitable and fast.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem and I found 1 solution. Recreate ClusterManager each time. I know that it doesn't fix the problem, but you won't have an error.

Answer (score 0):

With Kotlin, overriding onClusterUpdated method in DefaultClusterRenderer like this:

```
override fun onClusterUpdated(cluster: Cluster<MyModel>, marker: Marker) {}
```

It works for me!